# Type of triangle in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Problem statement:

> Write a query identifying the type of each record in the TRIANGLES
> table using its three side lengths. Output one of the following
> statements for each record in the table:
>
> - Not A Triangle: The given values of A, B, and C don't form a triangle.
> - Equilateral: It's a triangle with  sides of equal length.
> - Isosceles: It's a triangle with  sides of equal length.
> - Scalene: It's a triangle with  sides of differing lengths. Input Format
>
> The TRIANGLES table is described as follows:
>
> Each row in the table denotes the lengths of each of a triangle's
> three sides.

```
Sample Input
------------
A  B  C
20 20 23
20 20 20
20 21 22
13 14 30

Sample Output
-------------
Isosceles
Equilateral
Scalene
Not A Triangle
```

Attempt that did not work:

```
select
    case
        when A+B < C or A+C < B or B+C < A then "Not A Triangle"
        when A=B and B=C then "Equilateral"
        when A=B or A=C or B=C then "Isosceles"
        when A<>B and B<>C then "Scalene"

    end as triangles_type
    from TRIANGLES;
```

Comment: select case
when A=B and B=C then "Equilateral"
when A<>B and B<>C then "Scalene"
when A=B or A=C or B=C then "Isosceles"
when A+B < C or A+C < B or B+C < A then "Not A Triangle"
end as triangles_type
from TRIANGLES;

Comment: sample input 
A   B   C
20 20 23
20 20 20
20 21 22
13 14 30

sample output
sosceles
Equilateral
Scalene
Not A Triangle

Comment: @jpw i don't know how to add my code
i know it will be hard to read it but plz coperate i am new here

Comment: If I were to guess I think the problem is that you get scalene for the forth case and not 'not a triangle'. This is because the fourth case needs to be evaluated first, so move it up.

Comment: thanks @jpw i will must go through it.

Comment: This seems very procedural. Is that the way to go in SQL?

Comment: It is unknown why the give code "did not work", see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=221e9a4c0760709722b01253bb01785d

Answer (score 38):

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN A + B <= C or A + C <= B or B + C <= A THEN 'Not A Triangle'
    WHEN A = B and B = C THEN 'Equilateral'
    WHEN A = B or A = C or B = C THEN 'Isosceles'
    WHEN A <> B and B <> C THEN 'Scalene'
  END tuple
FROM TRIANGLES;
```

1. By using a case statement, check if a given input is a triangle or not.
2. If it is a triangle then check if all sides are same. If **true** the triangle type is 'Equilateral'.
3. If not, then check if any two sides are equal. If **true**, the triangle type is 'Isosceles'
4. In the case of not equal, any sides the triangle type is 'Scalene'. We can directly use **ELSE** also.

Comment: A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 18):

```
select case
when A+B <= C or A+C <= B or B+C <= A then "Not A Triangle"
when A=B and B=C then "Equilateral"
when A=B or A=C or B=C then "Isosceles"
else "Scalene"
end as triangles_type
from TRIANGLES;
```

Comment: what's the use of `end as triangles_type` in the query?

Comment: An explanation would be in order. Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38563985/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: <code>end as triangles_types</code> @ApthaGowda is for naming the column.

Answer (score 8):

Try below mentioned query. This will surely work.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN A + B > C AND A+C>B AND B+C>A THEN 
      CASE
        WHEN A = B AND B = C THEN 'Equilateral' 
        WHEN A = B OR B = C OR A = C THEN 'Isosceles' 
        ELSE 'Scalene' 
      END 
    ELSE 'Not A Triangle' 
  END FROM TRIANGLES;
```

**Explanation:**

First, check whether the values satisfies the requirement of a triangle(i.e sum of two sides must be greater than the other side)

*If above condition is true then, look for the type of the triangle*

- Equilateral - All sides are equal
- Isosceles - Any two sides are equal
- Scalene - All three sides are different

*If above condition is false then*

- Not A Triangle

Comment: this answer should be marked as the solution.

Comment: well explained thanks, @Gaurvu Kumar

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT  CASE
    WHEN A+B>C AND B+C>A AND A+C>B THEN
        CASE 
            WHEN A=B AND B=C THEN 'Equilateral'
            WHEN A=B or A=C OR B=C THEN 'Isosceles'
            ELSE 'Scalene'
        END
    ELSE 'Not A Triangle'
END
FROM TRIANGLES
```

- Step 1: First we select case to check if given input is a triangle or not
- Step 2: If it is a triangle then check for its type. So first case if all sides are the same, then the triangle type is `'Equilateral'`, then second case if any two sides are the same then the triangle type is `'Isosceles'`, otherwise the triangle type is `'Scalene'`.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
select case
    when (A+B<=C or B+C<=A or A+C<=B) then 'Not A Triangle'
    when (A=B and B=c) then 'Equilateral'
    when (A=B AND C<>B) or (B=C AND C<>A) or (A=C AND A<>B) then 'Isosceles'
else 'Scalene'
end as triangle_type
from TRIANGLES;
```

Here, it will strictly check for the type of the triangles.

Comment: Shouldn't `B=c` be `B=C`?

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is actually right. But the one little information **(Triangle's 'Right' Definition)** is missing on the question (which is not your fault) that **if two sides' sum is bigger OR EQUAL to another side then it's not a triangle**

The only thing you should do is putting '=' near of your '<'

```
select 
 case 
  when A+B <= C or A+C <= B or B+C <= A then "Not A Triangle"
  when A=B and B=C then "Equilateral"
  when A=B or A=C or B=C then "Isosceles"  
  when A<>B and B<>C then "Scalene" 


 end as triangles_type 
from TRIANGLES;
```

Comment: What does "Your answer" refer to?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN (A > 0 AND B > 0 AND C > 0 AND (A + B > C) AND (B + C > A) AND (A + C > B)) 
    THEN
    (
        CASE
            WHEN (A = B AND B = C) THEN 'Equilateral'
            WHEN (A = B OR B = C OR A = C) THEN 'Isosceles'
            ELSE 'Scalene'
        END
    )
    ELSE 'Not A Triangle'
END
FROM TRIANGLES;
```

Comment: Code is always good, but some context and explanation always helps. Check out 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question/7659#7659

Comment: [An explanation would be in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561938/type-of-triangle-in-mysql/45546188#comment118546145_38563985).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN (A + B <= C) OR (B+C <= A) OR (A+C <= B) THEN "Not A Triangle" 
WHEN (A=B) AND (B=C) THEN "Equilateral"
WHEN (A=B) OR (C=A) OR (B=C) THEN "Isosceles" 
ELSE "Scalene" 
END 
FROM TRIANGLES
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41906545/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle 11g this is working:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN A+B>C then case when A=B AND B=C THEN 'Equilateral'
   WHEN A=B OR B=C OR A=C THEN 'Isosceles'
   WHEN A!=B or B!=C OR A!=C THEN 'Scalene' END
   ELSE 'Not A Triangle' END
   FROM TRIANGLES;
```

Comment: [An explanation would be in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561938/type-of-triangle-in-mysql/45546188#comment118546145_38563985).

Answer (score 1):

**For MySQL:**

```
select
  case
      when (a+b>c) and (a+c>b) and (b+c>a) then
           case
              when (a=b) and (b=c) and (a=c) then 'Equilateral'
              when (a=b) or (b=c) or (a=c) then 'Isosceles'
              else 'Scalene'
           end
       else 'Not A Triangle'
    end    
from TRIANGLES
```

Comment: [An explanation would be in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561938/type-of-triangle-in-mysql/45546188#comment118546145_38563985). E.g., how and why is it different from previous answers?

Answer (score 1):

The below code will check all the possible cases of a triangle. this code will work 100%

```
select case
    when A+B<=C OR A+C<=B OR C+B<=A THEN "Not A Triangle"
    when (A<>B AND A+B>C) AND (B<>C AND B+C>A) AND (A<>C AND A+C>B) THEN
        "Scalene"
    when (A=B AND B<>C AND A+B>C) OR (B=C AND B<>A AND B+C>A) OR (A=C AND C<>B
          AND A+C>B) THEN "Isosceles"
    when A=B AND B=C THEN "Equilateral"
end as triangle
from TRIANGLES;
```

Comment: Rather than commenting "this works 100%" add some value to your answer by explaining what each line does.

Comment: The formatting near "THEN" (three instances) is all over the place. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

**MySQL with all test cases passed:**

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN A + B > C AND A+C>B AND B+C>A THEN CASE 
    WHEN A = B AND B = C THEN 'Equilateral' 
    WHEN A = B OR B = C OR A = C THEN 'Isosceles' 
    WHEN A != B OR B != C OR A != C THEN 'Scalene' 
END ELSE 'Not A Triangle' END FROM TRIANGLES;
```

Comment: Is all uppercase a convention (not a rhetorical question)?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN A + B > C 
              AND B + C > A 
              AND A + C > B THEN 
           CASE 
             WHEN A = B 
                  AND B = C THEN 'Equilateral' 
             WHEN A = B 
                   OR A = C 
                   OR B = C THEN 'Isosceles' 
             ELSE 'Scalene' 
           END 
         ELSE 'Not A Triangle' 
       END 
FROM   TRIANGLES;
```

Comment: [An explanation would be in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561938/type-of-triangle-in-mysql/45546188#comment118546145_38563985).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN (A+B>C AND B+C>A AND A+C>B) THEN
    (CASE
     WHEN A=B AND B=C AND A=C THEN 'Equilateral'
     WHEN A=B OR B=C OR A=C THEN 'Isosceles'
     ELSE 'Scalene'
     END)
    ELSE 'Not A Triangle'
END
FROM TRIANGLES;
```

Comment: Quite note: don't use single `` quotes for more than 1 line of code.

Comment: [An explanation would be in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561938/type-of-triangle-in-mysql/45546188#comment118546145_38563985).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL:

```
select
case 
    when ((A+B)<=C) || ((C+B)<=A) || ((A+C)<=B)  then 'Not A Triangle'
    when A=B && B=C && A=C then 'Equilateral'
    when ((A=B) && (A+B)>C) || ((B=C) && (B+C)>A)  then 'Isosceles'    
    when A!=B && B!=C && A!=C then 'Scalene' 
    end
from TRIANGLES;
```

Explanation:

**First**, check whether the values satisfies the requirement of a triangle(i.e sum of two sides must be greater than the other side) - **Not A Triangle**

Then, look for the type of the triangle

1. **Equilateral** - All sides are equal
2. **Isosceles** - Any two sides are equal(included additional condition of sum two sides greater than the other side - this can be ignored as we check the fundamental rule of a triangle as a first case)
3. **Scalene** - All three sides are different

Comment: Can you tell us what your answer does to improve on the high scoring answer below. Thank you.

Comment: @PeterSmith added explanation to my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Small thought: the final test is not need and could be replaced by `ELSE 'Scalene' as there are no other options by that point in the logic. Also the test for isosceles only requires that any two sides are equal, without testing against the third side.

Comment: Agreed, updated 'isosceles' case and leaving the conditions for 'Scalene' triangle untouched to relate to its definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
select CASE WHEN ((A+B)<=C OR (B+C)<=A OR (A+C)<=B ) THEN 'Not A Triangle'
       ELSE (case when (A=B) AND (B=C) AND (A=C) THEN 'Equilateral'
        WHEN (A=B) OR (B=C) OR (A=C) THEN 'Isosceles'
        WHEN (A<>B) AND (B<>C) AND (A<>C) THEN 'Scalene'
        END )
        END TYPET
FROM TRIANGLES

1. CHECK IF IT IS NOT A TRIANGLE
2. ELSE CHECK IF ALL SIDES ARE EQUAL THEN  'Equilateral'
3. IF ONLY TWO SIDES ARE EQUAL THEN Isosceles
4. IF NO SIDES ARE EQUAL THEN 'Scalene'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  
case
when ((A + B) <= C) or ((A + C) <= B) or ((C + B) <= A) then 'Not A Triangle' 
when (A = B and B = C) then 'Equilateral'
when (A = B or B = C or A = C) then 'Isosceles'
when (A != B and B != C and A != C)  then 'Scalene'
end  as Types_of_Triangles
from TRIANGLES;
```

Answer (score -1):

This answer is working well in [SQL Plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Plus), but not in [HackerRank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HackerRank) (I don’t know why).

Try this:

```
declare
    cursor mytriangle is select A, B, C from triangles;
    a triangles.A %type;
    b triangles.B %type;
    c triangles.C %type;
    begin
        open mytriangle;
        if mytriangle%isopen then
            loop
                fetch mytriangle into a, b, c;
                exit when mytriangle %notfound;
                case
                    when a+b<=c or b+c<=a or a+c<=b then
                        dbms_output.put_line('Not A Triangle');
                    when a=b and b=c then
                        dbms_output.put_line('Equilateral');
                    when a=b or b=c or c=a then
                        dbms_output.put_line('Isoceles');
                    when a+b>=c and b+c>=a and a+c>=b and a!=b and b!=c and c!=a then
                        dbms_output.put_line('Scalene');
                else
                    dbms_output.put_line('');
                end case;
            end loop;
            close mytriangle;
        else dbms_output.put_line('cannot open the cursor');
        end if;
    end;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
case
    when (a+b>c) and (b+c>a) and (c+a>b) then
        case
            when a=b and b=c then 'Equilateral'
            when a=b or b=c or c=a then 'Isosceles'
            else 'Scalene'
        end
    else 'Not A Triangle'
end 
from triangles;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take some time to read how to write a good answer. read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/338114) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: [An explanation would be in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561938/type-of-triangle-in-mysql/45546188#comment118546145_38563985).

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
SELECT 
      IF(A+B>C AND A+C>B AND B+C>A, 
      IF(A=B AND B=C, 'Equilateral', 
      IF(A=B OR B=C OR A=C, 'Isosceles', 'Scalene')), 
     'Not A Triangle') FROM TRIANGLES;
```

Comment: While this might provide an answer to the question, some explanation is required. Please update the comment with some explanation of how and why this solution works.

Comment: [An explanation would be in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561938/type-of-triangle-in-mysql/45546188#comment118546145_38563985).

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
select
    case
        when a=b and b=c then 'Equilateral'
        when a+b <=c or b+c<=a or a+c<b then 'Not A Triangle'
        when a=b or b=c or a=c then 'Isosceles'
        else 'Scalene'
    end
from TRIANGLES
```

Comment: [An explanation would be in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561938/type-of-triangle-in-mysql/45546188#comment118546145_38563985).

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  
      CASE 
WHEN ( ((A+B)<= C) OR  ((A+C)<= B) OR  ((B+C)<= A) ) THEN 'Not A Triangle'
ELSE 
    CASE 
        WHEN (A=B AND B=C ) THEN 'Equilateral'
        WHEN (A=B OR A=C OR B=C)THEN 'Isosceles'
        ELSE     'Scalene'
    END
END
from TRIANGLES;
```

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT    
  CASE 
    WHEN   (a + b)  <= c OR (a + c) <= b OR (b + c) <= a THEN 'Not a triangle' 
    WHEN    (a    =    b)    AND    (b    =    c)    AND    (a    =    c)    THEN    'Equilateral'
                WHEN    (a    =    b)    OR    (b    =    c)    OR    (a    =    c)    THEN    'Isosceles'
                WHEN    (a    <>    b)    AND    (b    <>    c)    AND    (a    <>    c)    THEN    'Scalene'    
        END    AS    TRIANGLES    
FROM    
        triangle;
```