# Determine type of triangle

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying the hacker rank type of triangle below where based on the 3 sides it has to be determined if the triangle is equilateral, isosceles, scaelene, or not a triangle.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/what-type-of-triangle/problem

I'm not sure why the code below isn't passing the test case.  Unfortunately, I can't download the test case to see why it isn't working.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN A = B AND B = C AND A = C THEN 'Equilateral' 
            WHEN (A = B AND B != C AND A != C)  OR (B = C AND A != B AND A != C)  OR (A = C AND A != B AND B != C) THEN 'Isosceles' 
            WHEN ((A + B) < C) OR ((B + C) < A) OR ((C + A) < B) THEN 'Not a triangle' 
            ELSE 'Scalene'  END 
FROM Triangles
```

Comment: I changed it to 'Not A Triangle', but it's still giving an error.

Comment: `((A + B) < C)` should be `((A + B) <= C)` etc.

Comment: the test case still errors out after making the change

Comment: Your problem is that your code will return `Isosceles` for e.g. `A=5 B=5 C=20` when that is not actually a triangle. Either of the answers below will fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks. Missed that use case..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type of Triangle in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561938/type-of-triangle-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN A + B > C AND A + C > B AND B + C > A THEN 
            CASE 
                WHEN A = B AND B = C THEN 'Equilateral' 
                WHEN A = B OR B = C OR A = C THEN 'Isosceles' 
                ELSE 'Scalene' END 
        ELSE 'Not A Triangle' END 
    FROM TRIANGLES
```

Only test for the type of triangle when it is a triangle.

Comment: I saw this as an answer from another post.  But I don't understand why the code I wrote doesn't work.

Comment: Beause, you are not checking for the condition of whether it is a triangle before declaring it as Scalene

Comment: @JonathanVanDam actually he's not checking if it's a triangle before calling it `Isosceles`

Comment: Thanks @Nick I misspoke on that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN A + B > C AND A+C>B AND B+C>A THEN 
   CASE WHEN A = B AND B = C THEN 'Equilateral' 
        WHEN A = B OR B = C OR A = C THEN 'Isosceles' 
        WHEN A != B OR B != C OR A != C THEN 'Scalene' 
   END 
   ELSE 'Not A Triangle' END FROM TRIANGLES;
```

The condition for scalene triangle does not include the following condition in your original query : Side 1 + Side 2 <= Side 3