# Types of Triangle in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Write a query identifying the type of each record in the TRIANGLES table using its three side lengths. Output one of the following statements for each record in the table:

Not A Triangle: The given values of A, B, and C don't form a triangle.
Equilateral: It's a triangle with sides of equal length.
Isosceles: It's a triangle with sides of equal length.
Scalene: It's a triangle with sides of differing lengths. Input Format
The TRIANGLES table is described as follows:

Each row in the table denotes the lengths of each of a triangle's three sides.

Sample Input

```
A  B  C  
------------
20 20 23 
20 20 20  
20 21 22  
13 14 30
```

Sample Output

```
Isosceles
Equilateral
Scalene
Not A Triangle
```

My code that's not working:

```
Begin
If(a+b>c) or (a+c>b) or (b+c>a) then
if (a=b!=c) then
dbms_output.put_line ('Isosceles');
elseif (a=b=c)
dbms_output.put_line ('Equilateral');
else (a!=b=!c)
dbms_output.put_line ('Scalene');
endif;

else 
dbms_output.put_line ('Not A Triangle');
endif;
end;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type of Triangle in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561938/type-of-triangle-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

IMO you should use this

```
SELECT a, b, c,
    CASE  
        WHEN NOT ((a+b>c) AND (a+c>b) AND (b+c>a)) THEN 'Not A Triangle'
        WHEN a = b AND b = c THEN 'Equilateral'
        WHEN a = b OR b = c OR c = a THEN 'Isosceles'
        ELSE 'Scalene'
    END AS result
FROM table_name;
```

Tested [in rextester](https://rextester.com/PPMXI1268)

```
    A   B   C   RESULT
1   20  20  23  Isosceles
2   20  20  20  Equilateral
3   20  21  22  Scalene
4   13  14  30  Not A Triangle
```